Bluetooth Connection Issues: AWEI T29 Pro Earbud Sound Fluctuations and Recurrent Bluetooth Disconnects on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
I am facing an issue using an AWEI T29 Pro Earbud and an iMICE E-i300 Bluetooth mouse simultaneously on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS.
Problem Details:
Earbud Connection: The AWEI T29 Pro earbud connects well, but the sound fluctuates frequently. It is configured with High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink, Codec SBC).
Bluetooth Mouse: The iMICE E-i300 Bluetooth mouse is also connected but seems to recurrently disconnect and reconnect.
Bluetooth Management: I installed Blueman to manage Bluetooth devices better, but it has not improved the situation.
Steps Taken:

Installed Blueman for advanced Bluetooth management.
Configured the output for the earbud to High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink, Codec SBC).

Question:

Is there any way to improve the Bluetooth connectivity and resolve the sound fluctuation issue with my earbud while using the mouse?
Are there any additional drivers, configurations, or settings that could help stabilize the connection and sound quality?

Thank you in advance for your help!
